# Как закрасить текст из option как placeholder?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать текст вида placeholder на select как в input-ах?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чекал уже 25 вариантов все равно текст не меняется как в input-ах?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
      <div class = "col-2"
           </div>
        <div class = "col-8"
```

```
                            <br/>
                            <div class="form-all">
           

              <br>
                                <div class="form-input">
                                    <input class="textInput sel" type="text" placeHolder="Full Name" class=" form-textbox" data-type="input-textbox" id="fullName" name="fullname" maxlength="40" size="30" value="" required/>
                <small id="FullNameHelpText" class="form-text text-muted" style="display:none;">Enter name!</small>
                </div>
                                <div class="form-input">

                <div class="form-input">
                  <select class="form-control sel" name = "place" id = "place" >
                    <option value="">Val1</option>
                    <option value="">Val2</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
                                <div class="form-input">
                                    <input class="textInput sel" type="text" placeHolder="Number" class=" form-textbox" data-type="input-textbox" id="phone" name="telefon" maxlength="35" size="30" value="" required/>
                  <small id="NumberHelpText" class="form-text text-muted" style="display:none;">Number!</small>
              </div>

                                <br/>
                                <button class="buton" type="button" name="step_1" size="30" onclick="ajaxrequest();"  id="sub_butt">Send</button>
                                <br><br>

                            </div>

                    </form>
</div>
```

код https://codepen.io/Keanu-Reeves123/pen/gOwOzGR

Comment: Вам просто нужно взять соответствующие цвета и прописать `color` и `background-color` для `.form-control`. Вам же надо точно такой же вид как и у текстовых `input'ов`?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется что вам не нужно делать цвет `select`-a таким же как и `placeholder`, потому что если в инпуте текст, который введет пользователь будет такого же цвета как и placeholder, то это будет не совсем корректно, если посмотреть cо стороны UX.

Стили можно просто переопределить в css. Таким образом можно изменить `background-color` селекта:

```
.form-input select {
    background-color: #eef2f7;
    border-color: #eef2f7;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]